# How to fit the ridge instance?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm getting the error (KeyError: 'target')  when I used

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
reg = Ridge(alpha=.1)

predictors = ["Temperature from the first internal sensor", "Outside temperature", "CPU Temperature", "Temperature from the second internal sensor", "Air Pressure", "Humidity"]

train = weather.loc[:"Thu 17 Feb 2022 08:57:02 PM"]
test = weather.loc["Thu 01 Dec 2022 10:00:02 AM":]

reg.fit(train[predictors], train["target"]) KeyError: 'target'
```

I tried to use another methods to fit the model but it didn't work, I'm using Colab to execute.

Comment: Post code and a minimal reproducible exampe, not images.

Comment: you got it!!!!!

Comment: error message indicates you don't have `target` column in your `train` df . maybe misspelled?  or letter cases don't match?

Comment: @eshirvana That is true, when I created a target column and filled it with numbers, just to test the results... It worked correctly